# css to replace characters in paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Already checked exisitng questions for this, but didn't find an exact match.

My aim is to replace characters (like spaces) on a webpage with a small image using css.

Example:

```
<p><span>This is a text</span></p>
```

becomes:

```
<p><span>ThisIMGisIMGaIMGtext</span></p>
```

(where IMG stands for a visible image (middot-pic for a space f.e.))

I cannot think of a suitable css selector. But myabe one of you guys (or girls) know a solution. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not having an ID, I assume you want it on all `<p><span>...</span></p>`. jQuery will help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("p span").html($("p span").html().replace(/ /g,'<img src="yourimg.gif" />'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I can't think of a way to achieve it in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

No, css doesn't have this ability. The only such things it can do are text-transform, which can do things like make it all uppercase.

Comment: Yup, I can't think of a way to do this either. You would need to put every word into an element, or replace the spaces by an element, to do something like this.

Comment: thats what i thought (and feared)

Answer (score 1):

If a monochromatic image will suffice, you could use a custom [web font](http://reisio.com/examples/webfonts/) that has the glyph of your choice *in place of* the usual empty space character ([U+0020](http://rishida.net/scripts/uniview/?char=0020&block=Basic%20Latin)).