# Removing extra spaces from GridView item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio, gridview

I'm trying to figure out to get rid of some spaces that Visual studio & the gridview.
It's a little annoyance that's been bothering me.

If I have the nicely formatted html inside the .

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Literal ID="myLit" runat="server" /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

it will produce the following output in Firebug -

```
<td> Text </td>
```

I realize that If I change my html formatting to following, it will work.

```
<ItemTemplate><asp:Literal ID="myLit" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
<td>Text</td>
```

The problem is that Vs2010 and/or the codemaid extension always reverts it to (which adds a space at the beginning)

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="lblJson" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
<td> Text</td>
```

I've had issues because of that extra space with some Jquery table sorting plugins.
Is there a way of telling the gridview to trim extra spaces from the html?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: As soon as you start using .NET, you surrender all control over HTML formatting. Bill wins again.

Comment: Ya, I'm using .net.  I'm just hoping that there's a property that I've never heard about called trim extra spaces.

Comment: There wouldn't be a css trick to get rid of the space that gets added?

Comment: Refer the article: [CSS to replace characters in paragraph tag] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950659/css-to-replace-characters-in-paragraph-tag, May be it will help you.

Comment: Ian, if you want to put your comment as an answer, I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ItemDataBound event to grab your content control using FindControl and remove the spaces.

Comment: The issue isn't with the content of the lblJson literal. It's with the spacing of the html as displayed in the html designer.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the values with the spaces inside you could remove them on the RowDataBound Event

```
 myLit = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
```

and then use simple string manipulation to remove them

or

it could be that the alignment is not set to left...

Then in the column section where you set the fields add this

```
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
```